# Using FAL in Extbase with more than one file

Tags: typo3

I tried to add a FileUpload to the extension glossary2. It works with one file, but no array is created which would show all the files entered.

Typo3 11.5.19
glossary2 5.0.9

Code in the TCA/Override

```
   'download' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:sm_glossary/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_smglossary_domain_model_glossary.download',
        'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig('download', [
                'appearance' => [
                    'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:media.addFileReference',
                    'elementBrowserEnabled' => 1,
                    "enabledControls" => [
                        "delete" => 1,
                        "dragdrop" => 1,
                        "hide" => 1,
                        "info" => 1,
                        "localize" => 1,
                        "sort" => 0
                    ],
                    "fileUploadAllowed" => 1,
                    "useSortable" => 1
                ],
                'type' => 'inline',
                'foreign_table' => 'sys_file_reference',
                'foreign_field' => 'uid_foreign',
                'foreign_sortby' => 'sorting_foreign',
                'foreign_table_field' => 'tablenames',
                'foreign_match_fields' => [
                    'fieldname' => 'download',
                ],
                'foreign_label' => 'uid_local',
                'foreign_selector' => 'uid_local',
                'maxitems' => 5,
            ]
        ),        
    ],
```

Domain/Model/

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace SM\SmGlossary\Domain\Model;

/**
 * Glossary
 */
class Glossary extends \JWeiland\Glossary2\Domain\Model\Glossary
{

    /**
     * Download
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
     * @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\ORM\Cascade("remove")
     */
    protected $download = null;


    /**
     * Returns the download
     *
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
     */
    public function getDownload()
    {
        return $this->download;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the download
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $download
     * @return void
     */
    public function setDownload(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $download)
    {
        $this->download = $download;
    }
}
```

I can insert more than one Files in Backend, but in Frontend f:debug show me only one:

```
SM\SmGlossary\Domain\Model\Glossary     prototype     persistent entity (uid=17, pid=147)
   download => protected TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReferenceprototypepersistent entity (uid=41, pid=147)
      uidLocal => protected 138 (integer)
      originalResource => protected NULL
      uid => protected41 (integer)
      _localizedUid => protected 41 (integer) modified
      _languageUid => protected 0 (integer) modified
      _versionedUid => protected 41 (integer) modified
      pid => protected 147 (integer)
```

I experimented with different settings in the TCA, but it did not achieve the desired success

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your model. You need to use an ObjectStorage, when you want to get more than one file.

Like:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace SM\SmGlossary\Domain\Model;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage;

/**
 * Glossary
 */
class Glossary extends \JWeiland\Glossary2\Domain\Model\Glossary
{

    /**
     * Download
     *
     * @var ObjectStorage<FileReference>
     * @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\ORM\Cascade("remove")
     */
    protected $download = null;


    /**
     * Returns the download
     *
     * @return ObjectStorage<FileReference>
     */
    public function getDownload()
    {
        return $this->download;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the download
     *
     * @param ObjectStorage<FileReference> $download
     * @return void
     */
    public function setDownload(ObjectStorage $download)
    {
        $this->download = $download;
    }
}
```

If you want to instanciate your model at some place, then you also need to add a constructor that instanciates your ObjectStorage for the `$download`:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->download = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectStorage::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have this problem fixed. If not, try updating your TCA as below:

```
'download' => [
    ......
    'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig('download', [
            ......
            'foreign_match_fields' => [
                'tablenames' => 'tx_smglossary_domain_model_glossary',
                'table_local' => 'sys_file',
            ],
            ......
        ]
    ),
    ......
],
```